# iPhone Safari Web Application not using cache at all?

Tags: iphone, caching, safari

guys, I've been developing an iphone web application for a while, and encountered a weird problem:

when open the web app in safari(with safari chrome, not starting it from home screen), safari can generate proper "If-Not-Modified-Since" and "If-None-Matches", so the server simply gives 304 Not Modified to speed up the process.

however, when starting the app from home screen, safari seems to forget these two headers, and server always replies with 200 OK...

any ideas for this?

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you at all.

http://new.efficientcoder.net/2009/06/webkitsafari-application-cache-work.html

Answer (score 0):

Check for consistency in the manifest file.

Somehow I also was dealing with 304 returncodes for my manifestfile (in normal safaribrowser mode on my iphone)..and always 200 returncodes when starting from homescreen.

In the end it was really stupid..
I didn't watch my chrome console for a while..which pointed out that my manifest-file was corrupt.